# Deleting characters that are repeating and constructive

Tags: python, loops, character

Create a program that prompts you to enter a sentence and deletes repeating characters if they are consecutive.
 
e.g 
`Input`
Whaat is this?
`Output`
What is this?

I have an error when I try to run this program:
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Here is code:

```
string = str(input("Enter the sentence: "))
    for i in string:
        if string[i] == string[i+1]:
            print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with range:

```
string = str(input("Enter the sentence: "))
    for i in range(len(string )-2):
        if string[i] == string[i+1]:
            print(i)
```

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @kovels From Harsha answer please try  the `range` function like this `range(len(string)-1)`

Comment: @kovels: oops.. I have modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a for loop to accomplish this:

```
st = list(input("Enter the sentence: "))
for c in range(len(st)-1):
    if st[c] == st[c+1]:
        st[c+1] = ''
print("".join(st))
```

---

Iterating using `for i in ...` assigns `i` to each iterated value of the desired iterable. You cannot index with it:

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
for i in a:
    print i
3
2
1
```

Instead, use `range`:

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
for i in range(len(a)):
    print i, a[i]
0, 3
1, 2
2, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that Python's for loop can do a lot more than just count indices. This part `for i in string` actually puts each character of `string` into the variable `i`. Therefore your code breaks because you are actually doing this:

```
if string['W'] == string['W' + 1]
```

In order for it to work, use the builtin function [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), with [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range).

```
string = str(input("Enter the sentence: "))
for i in range(len(string) - 1):
    if string[i] == string[i+1]:
         print(i)
```

UPDATE: As per the new edit, @A.J. Uppal gives the complete solution. In the future, you should consider using a debugger and going step by step through your program. That way you can check what is really happening and catch these kinds of errors much easier.